# No more lunchbox objectives?

Tags: fallout-shelter, android

Whenever I play fallout shelter I try to complete as many objectives as I can, and every objective has caps as a reward, no lunchboxes. Can you not get lunchboxes as an objective reward after the first 3 or 4 you get at the start, or are they just rarer to come across? If I want more lunchboxes do I have to purchase them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are simply rarer.  If you go through the objectives enough, using combination of skipping them and completing easy ones, you will eventually come across lunchbox objectives again.